# How to find a specific tagged interval within a find_all interval using beautifulsoup

Tags: html

I am trying to first find all the spans, after that look for those that have "Número de documento" in their get_text (), to continue with extracting from those span those that have the "nombcampo="it_ndoc_tom"" attribute.

This would be the structure of the spans that have "Número de documento" and with them their respective attributes that have different values, of which I only want to extract those that have "it_ndoc_tom"

```
[<span class='\"rSpnTitulo\"'>Número de documento<div campo="" class='\"glyphicon' editable.\"="" es="" glyphicon-edit\"="" style='\"float:right;\"' title='\"Éste'></div></span>, <span cetxt\"="" class='\"rSpnValor' idc0='\"1152723\"' nombcampo="it_ndoc_tom" paso="" vidc0='\"890102999\"'>890102999</span>]

[<span class='\"rSpnTitulo\"'>Número de documento<div campo="" class='\"glyphicon' editable.\"="" es="" glyphicon-edit\"="" style='\"float:right;\"' title='\"Éste'></div></span>, <span cetxt\"="" class='\"rSpnValor' idc0='\"1152725\"' nombcampo="ia_ndoc_ase" paso="" vidc0='\"52865608\"'>52865608</span>]

[<span class='\"rSpnTitulo\"'>Número de documento<div campo="" class='\"glyphicon' editable.\"="" es="" glyphicon-edit\"="" style='\"float:right;\"' title='\"Éste'></div></span>, <span cetxt\"="" class='\"rSpnValor' idc0='\"1152726\"' nombcampo="ib_ndoc_ben" paso="" vidc0='\"52865608\"'>52865608</span>]

[<span class='\"rSpnTitulo\"'>Número de documento<div campo="" class='\"glyphicon' editable.\"="" es="" glyphicon-edit\"="" style='\"float:right;\"' title='\"Éste'></div></span>, <span cetxt\"="" class='\"rSpnValor' idc0='\"1120863\"' nombcampo="ib_ndoc_ben" paso="" vidc0='\"860002082\"'>860002082</span>]
```

Currently I can already access those spans that have "Número de documento", but the problem is trying to search within those it found, those that have the attribute (nombcampo = it_ndoc_tom).

I share a bit of the code:

```
dataArray = soup.find_all('div', {'class': '\\\"rDivDatosAseg'})
        for data in dataArray:
            data_container = data
            ndoc_tom = data_container.find_all('span')
            if ndoc_tom[0].get_text() == "Número de documento":
               for span in ndoc_tom:
                   filt_ndoc_tom = span.find_all('span', {'nombcampo': 'it_ndoc_tom'})
                   print(filt_ndoc_tom)
```